# How to use first variable from first loop for second variable in another for loop in django template

Tags: python, django

How I can use the first variable from the first loop in the second loop in a Django template like this

```
{% for key in data %}
    {% for value in data.key %}
          <div>{{value}}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have the data is a nested dict in python like this

data =  { 'Google_Suite': {'Google Sheet': <QuerySet [<Course: Google Sheet level 1>, <Course: Google Sheet level 2>, <Course: Google Sheet level 3>]>,
'Google Docs': <QuerySet [<Course: Google Doc level 1>, <Course: Google Doc level 2>, <Course: Google Doc level 3>]>,
'Google Slide': <QuerySet [<Course: Google Slide level 2>, <Course: Google Slide level 3>]>},
'Language': {'English': <QuerySet [<Course: English level 1>]>}}

I tried but it's nothing to show

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
{% for key in data %}
{% for value in key %}
      <div>{{value}}</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries have the method `items` iterating over which gives both the key and the value so you can write:

```
{% for key, value in data.items %}
    <div>{{value}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```